# How to show MySQL errors from a failed Modx/xPDO query object?

Tags: mysql, modx, xpdo

How do I show the error mysql throws when I try to insert data into a custom table and the insert fails?

For example, below a bit of code that should(will) fail with an SQL error.

```
$insert = "some insert sql statement that will fail";

$myquery = $modx->query($insert);

    if(!$myquery){

        echo 'error occurred! <br>';

    }
```

How do I return what the error actually was [i.e. column mismatch, unique id exists etc.]?

Comment: I'm not sure, in the modx docs, they usually document the xpdo features as: $xpdo->query() instead of $modx->query().. http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/getting-started/creating-a-model-with-xpdo/defining-a-schema/defining-relationships

Comment: From `modx.class.php`: `class modX extends xPDO {…}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the examples in the [xPDO Getting Started guide](http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/getting-started/creating-a-model-with-xpdo/defining-a-schema/defining-relationships), `$modx` in this context appears to be a class extending `PDO` and the result resource object `$myquery` is likely a `PDOStatement` object.

You can therefore set an exception error mode on `$modx` as you would with a normal PDO object.

```
$modx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

to force it to throw errors on failure. By default, PDO errors silently; its error modes [are documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

**Correction:** [Looking into the xPDO source](https://github.com/modxcms/xpdo/blob/master/xpdo/xpdo.class.php#L2541) it does not *extend* `PDO`, but rather contains a `PDO` object as a property and implement PDO methods, passing them through to its connection property. So the `setAttribute()` call will be passed through to the underlying `PDO` object and should work accordingly.

[The xPDO constructor](http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/getting-started/fundamentals/xpdo,-the-class/the-xpdo-constructor) extends functionality from a normal PDO constructor slightly, and accepts an array of options in the 5th parameter where you may set the error mode, rather than setting it later via `setAttribute()`:

```
$xpdo = new xPDO($dsn, $user, $password, [], [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

Whichever method you choose to set it, you may wrap your code in a `try/catch` block to catch exceptions of type `PDOException` on error:

```
    try {
      $insert = "some insert sql statement that will fail";
      $myquery = $modx->query($insert);
   }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'error occurred! ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
    }
```

You may also more simply set the errormode to `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` and PHP will instead just emit `E_WARNING` messages, which unlike exceptions, are non-fatal.

I was able to verify all of this works as expected by setting up a quick test with xPDO.

Answer (score 5):

There is a little bit easier way to track your custom xpdo request.

```
$c = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$c->where(array(
    'id1' => 1
));

// print request for control
print_r($c->toSQL());

$s = $c->prepare();
$s->execute();

print_r($s->errorInfo());
```

After execution we can catch an error:

```
Array ( [0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'modResource.id1' in 'where clause' )
```

It's all because xpdo use pdo and controls execution with it's help. Some code from xpdo source:

```
/**
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdo-errorinfo.php
 */
public function errorInfo() {
    if (!$this->connect()) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->pdo->errorInfo();
}
```

Comment: Agreed - this is the MODX way to do it.